# Attempt to Connect to MySQL Through PHP Throws Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to use PHP to make a connection to a MySQL database as part of a website, and repeatedly getting two errors:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/html/file.php on line 12
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on
>   boolean in /var/www/html/file.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/file.php on line 20

My code is just connecting and one query:

```
<?php
//Error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
//Server data
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
$tblname = "table";
//Connection
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, null);
//Query
$sql = 'SELECT column1 FROM table';
//Send query
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$connect->close();
?>
```

Line 12 refers to `$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, null);` and line 20 refers to `$result = $connect->query($sql);`

I've done a lot of searching for what might be the matter; if anyone has some insight, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

EDIT: I needed to setup a new user, problem is solved. Thanks all.

Comment: Can you connect using `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: Thinking you simply using the wrong password.

Comment: There can also be a thing that you can only login with the root user if you're logged in with the system root user, gave me some headaches while setting up my first linux server.

Comment: Also remove the `, null)` at the end of the connect.

Comment: @KhorneHoly thats very true for MariaDB

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Had the same going on with mysql on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I can, I made certain that the password I'm using matched that in the user table of the mysql database.

Comment: @KhorneHoly That's good to know, thank you! I'll set up another user.

Comment: @KhorneHoly That did the trick, thanks!